How do you get divine protection?
By divine protection I mean some higher power always looking after you so you don't suffer too much. Protection against major crisis like enemies, wrong decisions, conspiracies, violent bad people etc. Its especially concerning that past life karma also affects us and you never know how it will manifest in your life. I have seen that in Vedic astrology too some people get divine protection by birth but what about others like me?
I am not asking for protection against black magic and spirit.

This is what Gita says on this issue.
God helps His devotees
Whoever, being devoted to Me solely, engage themselves always in contemplation and worship of Me – to such ever-steadfast devotees I ensure the procurement of all their wants and preservation of their assets (worldly interests).
Gita 9.22
God only helps great devotees. Others have to live according to their karma.

How to become great devotee?

Ananyas chintayanto mam.. this grants the supreme protection in all ways. All other rituals, travelling to holy places, tapasya, visiting a temple, meeting saints, singing prayers, etc. are to come to this platform of taila-dharavat smarana (constant meditation like an oil which drips from one vessel to another). Whoever can do this will become a great devotee very soon by the Lord's mercy.

For that you should first start the sadhana of a deity. After growing spiritually on this field, you'll receive the grace of the deity. Once you get the grace of deity, the deity will protect you.
Another thing you can do is -- Kavach path. Start chanting kavach of your ista deva. The more you chant, its better.
Om tat sat

Yes I was checking Shiva kavach but its tantric so I got a bit afraid of going on with
